Problem with config file in Keplergl Python
I want to build an news interactive map. The app would get latest news of a website, try to regex location of news and if so, insert them as points in a map, where a user could navigate and click on the points to view the news.
To do so, I got ChatGPT to create a geojson featurecollection file, containing features-points of cities with their geometry.coordinates, which then I enriched with the fetched data and inserted them in properties.name, title, date, and url of the news site as follows:
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    23.6481,
                    37.9439
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "Πειραιάς",
                "title": "Πειραιάς: Δύο συλλήψεις για ληστείες σε βάρος ανηλίκων",
                "date": "Friday, 24 May 2024 19:27:24",
                "url": "https://www.news247.gr/ellada/peiraias-dio-sillipseis-gia-listeies-se-varos-anilikon/"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    22.8812,
                    41.00129999999999
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "Κιλκίς",
                "title": "Έγκλημα στο Κιλκίς: Προσωρινά κρατούμενοι οι δύο ανήλικοι κατηγορούμενοι",
                "date": "Thursday, 23 May 2024 17:17:47",
                "url": "https://www.news247.gr/ellada/egklima-sto-kilkis-prosorina-kratoumenoi-oi-dio-anilikoi-katigoroumenoi/"
            }
        }

    ]
}

My crafted config is as follows:
{
    "version": "v1",
    "config": {
        "visState": {
            "filters": [],
            "layers": [],
            "interactionConfig": {}
        },
        "mapState": {
            "bearing": -4.928571428571431,
            "dragRotate": "True",
            "latitude": 37.97,
            "longitude": 23.72,
            "pitch": 30,
            "zoom": 8.655984704565685,
            "isSplit": "False"
        },
        "mapStyle": {
            "styleType": "light",
            "topLayerGroups": {},
            "visibleLayerGroups": {
                "label": "True",
                "road": "False",
                "border": "True",
                "building": "False",
                "water": "True",
                "land": "True"
            }
        }
    }
}

My code is as follows:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from keplergl import KeplerGl
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import json
import re
import time
import pprint
import html
import random


def get_sitemap():
    return requests.get('https://www.news247.gr/news-sitemap.xml').text

def fix_minor(title):
    fixed_title = title.replace('\n', ' ')
    # Replace multiple spaces with a single space
    fixed_title = ' '.join(fixed_title.split())
    fixed_title = html.unescape(fixed_title)
    return fixed_title

def get_news_info(news):
    url = news.find('loc').text
    date = datetime.fromisoformat(news.find('publication_date').text).strftime("%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
    title = fix_minor(news.find('title').text)
    return {'title': title, 'date': date, 'url': url}

def load_geoJson():
    with open('geo_gr.json', 'r') as file:
        geo = json.loads(file.read())
    return geo

def load_config():
    with open('ub.json', 'r') as cc:
        custom_config = json.loads(cc.read())
    return custom_config

# main

# get latest news
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_sitemap(), 'xml')
news = soup.find_all('url')


# append latest news to list
all_news = []
for item in news:
    all_news.append(get_news_info(item))

# load geo json and perform geo regex
tagList = []
locations = []

geo = load_geoJson()
features = []
out_geo = {}
out_geo.update({"type": "FeatureCollection"})

for item in all_news:
    for location in geo['features']:
        re_location = re.search(location['properties']['name'], item['title'])
        if re_location:
            location['properties'].update({'title':item['title'], 'date':item['date'], 'url':item['url']})
            for coord in range(len(location['geometry']['coordinates'])):
                location['geometry']['coordinates'][coord] = location['geometry']['coordinates'][coord] + round(random.uniform(0.001, 0.003), 4)
            features.append(location)

out_geo.update({'features':features})   

map_ = KeplerGl(height=600, data={'feature_collection': out_geo}, config=load_config())

# Save the map to an HTML file
map_.save_to_html(file_name="index1.html")


The code does work, yet the problem that I want to solve is the editing of the config file. More specifically, I cannot find a way to insert the data correctly in config.visState.layer, so that I can perform basic layer editing, such as change in color, point radius, stroke, etc and not get the default settings.
Thank you in advance for any help and I would like to apologize for any inconvenience.

I would advise using a config.yaml file to update the layer config in a loop so that each layer uses the config yaml as a template to build the layer config.
Here is an example of a yaml file I have used:
layers:
        id: "<< name >>"
        type: "point" 
        config:
            dataId: "<< name >>"
            label: "<< name >>"
            isVisible: true
            color: "<< color >>"
            highlightColor: "<< highlightColor >>"
            visConfig:
                opacity: "<< opacity >>"
                strokeOpacity: 0.8
                thickness: "<< thickness >>"
                stroked: true
                filled: true
                radius: "<< radius >>"
            columns: 
                lat: "<< latitude_column_name >>"
                lng: "<< longitude_column_name >>"

Then you could have some default values and code to check if a value is present in the input data and if it isn't simply use the default value from the yaml file.
